# Typescript type parameter not inferred from generic class as expected

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

In this example, I'm using a parameter type `(keyof TFoo)[]` to expect an array that includes any keys from `TFoo`, to keep the example simple, but I'm seeing the same behavior with inference of type parameters any time I use the pattern `<T, TSomeClass extends SomeClass<T>>`. It seems to correctly infer the type `TFoo` as it applies to the class for the first `fooBarBad` function parameter `bar`, so in this example it identifies `TBar` as `Bar<{ a: number, b: number }>`, but for the second parameter `fooKeys`, it infers `TFoo` to instead be `{ a: any, c: any }`, which it's getting from the values passed in the array. I could see it possibly trying to infer `TFoo` in either of those ways, but I would at least expect it to apply the same inferred value of `TFoo` for both function parameters, as they both refer to the same type parameter `TFoo`.

```
class Bar<TFoo> {
  constructor(foo: TFoo) {}
}

function fooBarBad<TFoo, TBar extends Bar<TFoo>>(bar: TBar, fooKeys: (keyof TFoo)[]) {}

// No error, but I expect one - fooKeys is instead inferred to be ('a' | 'c')[]
fooBarBad(new Bar({ a: 1, b: 2 }), ['a', 'c']);
```

[image]

Is there some other way I can declare this to get the inference I want? Or some trick to force it?

A simpler example infers as I would expect.

```
function fooBar<TFoo>(foo: TFoo, fooKeys: (keyof TFoo)[]) {}

// Error as expected - 'c' is not a key of TFoo
fooBar({ a: 1, b: 2 }, ['a', 'c']);
```

[image: Simple case infers as expected]

Comment: The example is a bit too minimal because the type `Bar<TFoo>` does not depend structurally on `TFoo`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w1A3kw).  It's just a constructor parameter, which is a static property and has nothing to do with the instance type.  Could you [edit] that so that `TFoo` shows up somewhere in the instance type of `Bar`?   Perhaps like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK9dKN)?

Comment: @jcalz - yes you're right, I think I've over-simplified my example, I'll work on it...

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript prioritizes  the arguments when looking for inference targets. The type of `TBar` is inferred by the first argument while `TFoo` is inferred by the second argument and *not* via the constraint of `TFoo`.

We can simplify your example to have a single generic parameter `TFoo`.

```
class Bar<TFoo> {
  constructor(foo: TFoo) {}
}

function fooBarBad<TFoo>(bar: Bar<TFoo>, fooKeys: (keyof TFoo)[]) {}
```

Which leads to the correct inference.

```
fooBarBad(
  new Bar({ a: 1, b: 2 }), ['a', 'c']
//                               ~~~ Type '"c"' is not assignable
//                                   to type '"a" | "b"'
)
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYCcA8AVAYgewwPmgbwChppgMA7CAFwQFdhKMEAKAMywC5p0sBKfAXwKCCLGmXoBLctDYZ4CeABNUmHEwBGiTvJVZsAGhlYA0gFMAnhE5MA1hYwsuqngG0AunzzDZ8pUzKmAO5wiEx40GCcAIyG6pwATND8PIYuAORgaYZpwGkeANwEAPRFxGXlFZVV1eUAfvVc5gAOptBpAETA7WnQEjBkGJQRUBIA5mRg6iCtDNCUza0dYO3QAD7Q7erdQA)

Comment: This definitely answers my question as asked, and is great to understand how typescript handles this, but as @jcalz commented, I may have simplified my example too much to be relevant for my actual usage. I'll update my question to be a little closer to my real world example. Thanks!